# Cómo podría hacer una función que recibe un vector de números reales

Tags: r

Desarrolle una función que reciba un vector de números reales y un número real x, tal que indique el porcentaje de elementos menores o iguales a un valor x.

No encuentro la forma de realizarlos, solicito de su ayuda por favor, gracias

Comment: Bienvenido Joan Alejandro Mendez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Trata de agregar algún ejemplo del código que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

En R sería de la siguiente manera

```
porcentaje_menores <- function(y,x) {
  return(100*length(y[y<=x])/length(y))
}

porcentaje_menores(1:10,5)
porcentaje_menores(1:10,1)
```

Con `lenght()` regresa el numero de elementos en un vector, y con `y[y<=x]` filtramos los valores de `y` menores o iguales a `x`. El resto es envolver la formula de porcentaje dentro de una función `r` `porcentaje_menores`.

Nota: Faltaría agregar pruebas sobre los parámetros de la función para evitar errores.